# Register Castle Windsor Logging Facility

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, castle-windsor, castle

I am new to IOC and Castle Windsor. I would like to use the logging facility provided by Castle per their documentation

http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Logging-Facility.ashx

I am trying to register the facility per the documentation recommendation

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.Log4net).WithConfig("log4net.config"));
```

I have referenced the Castle.Core and Castle.Facilities.Logging dll's

at compile time I get the following error

```
The type 'Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer.AddFacility<T>(System.Func<T,object>)'. 
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility' to 'Castle.MicroKernel.IFacility'. C:\Sports\app\Daedalsoft.Sports.ApplicationServices\WindsorServiceInstaller.cs
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may have a reference to Castle.MicroKernel.dll from a previous version. Castle.MicroKernel was merged into Castle.Windsor.dll, if you're using the latest version of Windsor you shouldn't have Castle.MicroKernel.dll.

Also make sure you have a reference to Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.dll and log4net.dll